# Espresso-web framework with cordova android project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-testing, android-espresso

I’m trying to write UI tests for a cordova hybrid app using espresso-web framework[1]. 
Even after mentioning the required dependencies in build.gradle, the tests are not running and the build is erroring out with the dependency packages not found. But when I’m trying out the same thing with a standalone android studio project (non- cordova), I’m able to succeed.
I think it has something to do with the difference in the default project structure of cordova with respect to that of Android Studio. The classes in the packages under the androidTest folder are not being recognized as Test Classes in the cordova project. 
How can I integrate espresso-web framework in a cordova android project successfully?

Comment: quoting the actual error messages might be helpful...

Comment: error: package android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar does not exist
error: package android.support.test.espresso.web.webdriver does not exist
error: package android.support.test.espresso.web.webdriver does not exist

Comment: Error:(24, 51) error: package android.support.test.espresso.web.webdriver does not exist
Error:(25, 36) error: package android.support.test.filters does not exist
Error:(26, 33) error: package android.support.test.rule does not exist
Error:(27, 35) error: package android.support.test.runner does not exist
Error:(30, 24) error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
Error:(50, 2) error: cannot find symbol class LargeTest
Error:(51, 2) error: cannot find symbol class RunWith
Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Comment: I think the dependency errors are because you're doing a lot of the configuration yourself. I started a simple Cordova app, added an espresso test under src/androidTest/[appNamespace]/... and it failed until I installed this plugin: https://github.com/cvuser0/cordova-plugin-java7 ...this forces Cordova to use an SDK version that you can write Espresso tests with (i.e. generics for the ActivityTestRule<YourActivity>)